# kdb/q How do I save a kdb workspace using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, kdb

I'm using VS Code as my IDE, and I know that people use notation like below to load up a workspace:

```
\l C:/git/.../NameOfFile.q
```

I think this is called saving a (kdb) workspace, how can I do that so all I need to do is call the line above and start using the functions within it?

Comment: what is a `.q` file? VSC saves the workspace stuff automatically

Comment: A kdb "workspace" is generally created by loading a database and script(s) - scripts in turn define functions, variables, in-memory tables etc. You don't generally save out the in-memory contents of a workspace to load them back in again, you load a database and script(s) to re-create the workspace. So to answer your question yes - you would load a script as per your example and that script can presumable either load other scripts or define everything you need, and/or load a database etc.

Comment: where are you running that command? the integrated terminal? what shell?

Answer (score 0):

The \l notation is used to load a file (and its functions) to a new file.

So for example, if I wanted to use the functions that I created in a previous q file called NameOfFile.q, I would write this line item at the top of a new file:

```
\l C:/git/.../NameOfFile.q
```

This way, I can access all of those functions. This helps contain all of the relevant functions in one place, allowing your code to be kept neater and more concise.